# sql server update Query pls tell

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
Update o Set o.OpBal=0 from eOpBalance o
inner join EAccountMaster a on a.Id=o.AcId
where a.GLId='90999B68-3D50-E411-81CA-E41F13B3B802' and o.SocId='DEFE9D09-A20E-43AC-8C4C-55D00FF297B2'
```

in this Query what is the meaning o. set and a.

Comment: o and a are the alias name of the table eOpBalance and EAccountMaster respectively

Answer (score 0):

Updating the table eOpBalance(alias Name o) column OpBal, and the record matches with the table  EAccountMaster(alias Name a).